# RailsAdmin papertrail generating empty history

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, paper-trail-gem

In my app I have installed rails-admin-history-rollback for PaperTrail gem, the history is working, however, it's also generating empty changes.

I followed the configuration and I don't know if i missed something

config on Rails-admin initializer:

```rb
RailsAdmin.config do |config|
 config.audit_with :paper_trail, 'Admin', 'PaperTrail::Version'

 PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL = ['Residence']

  config.actions do
    history_index do
      only PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL
    end

    history_show do
      only PAPER_TRAIL_AUDIT_MODEL
    end
  end
 end
end
```

The changes life cycle has a lot of useless/empty changes.

[List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfcJG.png)

[Empty change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1TdE.png)

[Correct change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5WVg.png)

Comment: To understand what PT is doing at the model level, the rails console can be very useful. Going a step further, our [bug report script](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail/blob/master/.github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE/bug_report.md) can be helpful for isolating an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does your model have on its body this class method?

```
has_paper_trail
```

Another thing it could be is i know that inherited models (think rails STI) won't show on rails admin because papertrail will save the item_type with the parent class and rails admin will look for it with the children class.

Could you check the versions table after changing something on your model?